# Convert 7 character Integer to Number between 0 and 100

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

I'm currently trying to implement a function that converts a random hex hash with 64 characters into a number between 0 and 100. I have following code so far:

```
// Random hash
hash = 'f0ca70ef5e3942314d577ad32002d247cc28f0b503f775a0af2475917867708e';

function getResolvedTicket(hash) {
    let resolvedDecimal = parseInt(hash.substr(-6), 16);
    console.log(resolvedDecimal); // this always prints out a 7 character int, in this case '6779022'

    // Do something with resolvedDecimal to convert is to a number between 0 and 100 (with 2-3 decimals)
}
```

What is an elegant way to do this?

**EDIT**:

I am basically using this provably fair system, just without the nonce: https://thebitcoinstrip.com/a-guide-to-provable-fairness-in-online-casinos/
If anyone is interested read this :)

Comment: Are `0` and `100` included? Do you need a perfectly uniform distribution?

Comment: What's the purpose of the conversion? Do the numbers need to be unique or just random? Would it matter if two different hashes generated the same number? You should explain the problem in more depth as there may be a better overall approach.

Comment: The purpose is a provably fair system for a little gambling website. The numbers have to be unique to the hash, so every time when I use the getResolvedTicket function on the hash it should spit out the same ticket. It is ok if different hashes generate the same number.

Comment: Whenever hash is created store a random number between 0-100 using hash as a lookup key

Comment: Also, is it OK if the ticket number is predictable, knowing the hash?

Comment: That is ok since the numbers out of which the hash gets calculated are published at the end of the round, it is impossible to get the hash before the round finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

```
function getResolvedTicket(hash) {
  let resolvedDecimal = parseInt(hash.substr(1, 5), 16);
  let ticket = resolvedDecimal%(100000)/1000;
  return ticket;
}
```

Converting the first 5 characters of the hash to decimal, then dividing with 100000 and then dividing the modulus with 1000. Always getting a ticket with 3 decimals now.

was actually pretty easy to solve once I wrapped my head around it :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a modulo operation is that the results are not going to be uniform. Some ticket numbers will be picked more often than others.

If uniform results are required, the best way would probably to use the hash as a seed to feed your own PRNG such as [Mersenne Twister](https://gist.github.com/banksean/300494).

With the code provided in the above link, best results will then be achieved by doing:

```js
Math.floor(MersenneTwister.genrand_res53() * 101)
```

where `genrand_res53()` gives a float in `[0,1)` with 53-bit resolution.

Comment: Its for a school project, so I think that it is good enough. Still thanks for pointing out!